# Pandas plots don't align on specific date (month start vs month end)

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have some monthly data that I want to plot. But of course monthly alignment is important: either month start (e.g. 01-01-2000) or month end (e.g. 31-01-2000). However, when plotting, I see no difference between month start and month end.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

input = [10., 12., 15., 13.,  9., 20., 17., 21., 23., 16., 15., 16.]
index1 = pd.date_range(start='2000-01-31', end='2000-12-31', freq='M')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(input, index=index1)
index2 = pd.date_range(start='2000-01-01', end='2000-12-01', freq='MS')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(input, index=index2)

ax = df1.plot()
df2.plot(ax=ax)
```

I get this output:

[image]

While I would expect this:

[image]

Is this a bug, or did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to use [plot_date](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot_date.html) from matplotlib.

```
from matplotlib.dates import YearLocator, MonthLocator, DateFormatter
years = YearLocator()   # every year
months = MonthLocator()  # every month
monthsFmt = DateFormatter('%b')
```

Then

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(df1.index, df1[0], '-')
ax.plot_date(df2.index, df2[0], '-')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthsFmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)
ax.autoscale_view()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: OK, thanks. still seems that `pandas.DataFrame.plot` should do it correctly.

Comment: @JHBonarius, you are right. It "should". [github: DatetimeIndex not formatted for plots](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18153) would help you understand why it does not. Meanwhile, matplotlib solution works fine.